# Transferring layers from background pages to foreground pages

Tags: microsoft-visio, layers

Is there a way to transfer the layers I have made on a background page to a new foreground page? So if I make a new page as a foreground page with a background page containing layers they will automatically be transferred to the foreground page?
If so, how do I do it? - A workaround are appreciated as well.

Thank you
//Peter

Answer (score 0):

Put a shape (any shape will do - e.g. just a plain rectangle) on the background page, assign it to all the layers you want to transfer. Cut and Paste the shape to the new page. The shape can then be deleted - the layers will have been transferred.